Unidentified small bumps on a plant leaves
I have a Ficus virens.
The surface in one of the leave have bump.
Only 1-2 have such attributes.
Does any one know what is it? Virus?
Need to deal with it? Or just leave it alone?


They are just gall (you see many in the gallery at bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall).
The gall is usually just a reaction of the plant, so not a bad things galls themselves (so often green and producing photosynthesis). Just if the problem is increasing too much, you may check the origin (and so usually we seen a photo of the bottom part of leave), so when you know what is the cause (often which insect), so you can try to fight it: traps, oils, insecticides, etc.

Or, in short @JingCodeGuy show us what's on the underside of the leafs. Or watch them with a LED @ night. Nothing moving? We're gonna need a proper microscope then, not that hobby stuff I have.
